# How to run an SSIS package from Visual Basic 6?

Tags: sql-server, vb6, ssis

Can anyone provide some information on how to run an integration services package, on an SQL server 2005 instance, from Visual Basic 6?

Any help at all is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `xp_cmdshell` enabled, if it's not, execute: `sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', '1'` in SSMS on your server.

Create a store procedure, and put the following code in it:

```
DECLARE @SSISPackage VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @variable_value1 varchar(255)
DECLARE @Result int

SET @SSISPackage = 'C:\path_to_the_package\package_name.dtsx'
SET @cmd = 'dtexec /F "' + @SSISPackage + '"'   
// if you have variables in the package that need to be set up
// add them here
SET @cmd = @cmd + ' /SET \Package.Variables[User::somevariable1].Properties[Value];"' + @variable_value1 + '"'
SET @cmd = @cmd + ' /SET \Package.Variables[User::somevariable2].Properties[Value];"' + @variable_value2 + '"'
SET @cmd = @cmd + ' /SET \Package.Variables[User::somevariable3].Properties[Value];"' + @variable_value3 + '"'

EXECUTE @Result = master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, NO_OUTPUT
```

Then, call the stored procedure from VB6, via an ADODB.Command.

You have examples here:

- **SSIS**: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1395
- **ADODB.Command**: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/simple_sp_vb6.aspx

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from Dan S, what worked for me was:

Create a Stored Procedure which calls the package:

1. Right click on your SSIS package and choose 'Execute'.
2. In the Execute Package window click the 'Script' button.
3. Add to the top of the generated script:

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE sp_NewProcedureName
   AS
   BEGIN
   ```
4. And add to the bottom of the generated script:

   ```
   END
   GO
   ```
5. Execute this script to create the Stored Procedure.

Then use code to call the Stored Procedure

6. This code worked for me:

   ```
   Set adodbConn = New ADODB.Connection
   adodbConn.Open "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=yourSQLServer; Initial Catalog=yourDB; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
   Set adodbCMD = New ADODB.Command
   With adodbCMD
       .ActiveConnection = adodbConn
       .CommandText = "dbo.sp_NewProcedureName"
       .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
       .CommandTimeout = 0
       .Execute
   End With
   Set adodbCMD = Nothing
   adodbConn.Close
   Set adodbConn = Nothing
   ```

I needed to add a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library" to my VBA code.

I know it's an answer to an old question, but hopefully my answer brings everything in together in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest is to shell out and [run dtexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx)

Alternatively, you could [use the using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts assemblies](http://blogs.msdn.com/michen/archive/2007/03/22/running-ssis-package-programmatically.aspx) in .NET and wrap it in COM (or an EXE) and then call it from VB6.

That second link has some other options which might apply to VB6 in some way, but would probably all result in wrapping the .NET code in a COM object or an EXE.